# GetServletContext returning null in a class that extends HttpServlet

Tags: java, servlets

Ther is class that extends HttpServlet and trying to access variables set in different class

The following line of code in the class that extends HttpServlet is throwing a NullPOinterException:

```
SomeObject x =  getServletContext().getAttribute("x");
```

Ideas?

Comment: on which web container your application is deployed?

Comment: `int x =  getServletContext().getAttribute("x");` will this compile ?

Comment: But HttpServlet.getServletContext().getAttribute(String) is returning Object, not int. So it won't compile unless you have something different in your code.

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski: sorry you are correct. I was just trying to use a simplified example. I am trying to return an object.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you have overridden the init(ServletConfig cfg) method in your Servlet class and did not call the super.init(cfg) to do the standard setup stuff, resulting in an empty context.

Comment: @redman Maybe you are using an IDE-generated class that does override it?

Comment: I had accidentally overridden  init(ServletConfig cfg) method and kept method body blank. After removing this method definition, getServletContext() worked.  Thanks.